# Cannot get the right result by condition

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string like this:

> This your own todos list on the day, don't forgot it! ;), N Task Status, 0. xcv active, 1. xcv active (4)

What I need it's to find all the `,` (commas) in this string and replace them with a space, except when before the `,` stands a `y` letter.

To make it I creates a regular expresssion:

```
let str = 'This your own todos list on the day, don\'t forgot it! ;), N Task Status, 0. xcv active, 1. xcv active (4)';

str.match(/,/g);
```

But it founds all `,` in the string without filtering the case of `y,`.

I also tried these solutions:

```
str.match(/[^y],/g);
str.match(/[^],/g);
```

but inserting these regex in a replace they trim the commas with the letter before

```js
let str = 'This your own todos list on the day, don\'t forgot it! ;), N Task Status, 0. xcv active, 1. xcv active (4)';

alert(str.replace(/([^y]),/g, '\n'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.match(/[^y],/g)` will actually return you all the commas with the chars behind them.

If the point is to count those commas, then no other modification is actually needed - `str.match(/[^y],/g).length` will return you a number of those commas not after `y`.

If the point is to remove the commas which are appearing after any chars except `y`, that's how you would do that:

```js
let str = 'This your own todos list on the day, don\'t forgot it! ;), N Task Status, 0. xcv active, 1. xcv active (4)';

// count the commas
console.log(str.match(/[^y],/g).length);

// remove commas from the string
console.log(str.replace(/([^y]),/g,"$1 "));
```